# Drag and Drop через react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: reactjs, drag-n-drop

делаю элемент. и не как не могу понять в чем ошибка, не видит элемента с таким айди
Помогите пожалуйста, это у меня повылазило,и я не вижу где айди накинуть нужное, или у него...

[image: Ошибка]

сам элемент

```
<div className="container-draggable">
                  <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
                    <Droppable droppableId="exercises">
                      {(provided) => (
                        <div
                          {...provided.droppableProps}
                          ref={provided.innerRef}
                        >
                          {training.exercises.map((exercise, index) => {
                            return (
                              <Draggable
                                key={exercise.exercise_id}
                                draggableId={`${exercise.exercise_id}`}
                                index={index}
                              >
                                {(provided) => (
                                  <div
                                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                                    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                    className={s.template_detail_exercises}
                                  >
                                    <div
                                      className={
                                        s.template_detail_exercises_desc
                                      }
                                    >
                                      <p>тут еще элементы</p>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                )}
                              </Draggable>
                            );
                          })}
                          {provided.placeholder}
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Droppable>
                  </DragDropContext>
                </div>
```

Comment: реализацию onDragEnd добавь, возможно проблема там. Еще рукаписную exercises.

Comment: я там оставил просто консоль лог пока, так как она должна перетаскиваться и без какой либо функций, просто не сохраняться.

Comment: warning до перетаскивания или после?

Comment: при рендере, все норм, а как пытаюсь взять элемент и перенести, то, ни чего не происходит, и сыпет варнинги

Comment: возможная причина то что либа не совместима с текушим react, она уже года 2 не обновлялась, да и синтексис у него стремный. Если не критично просто юзай другую либу, а то исохдя из того что я успел посмотреть вроде все написано корректно.

Comment: спасибо. я тоже смотрю, что не должно быть таких ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Может кто столкнётся, с такой же проблемой, То все оказалось, так просто, что аж глупо.

в Droppable
необходимо добавить ключ, без него не работает

```
<Droppable droppableId="exercises" key={index}>
```

в моем случае, он такой от верхнего элемента.